# Why does Win10 version of rsync modify file owner/perms even if --perms option is set?

Tags: windows-10, security, permissions, rsync, ownership

I use [Grsync](https://sourceforge.net/projects/grsync/)'s bundled rsync.exe, and have a following simple .bat script in place to sync the folder to an E drive:

```
rsync.exe -r --perms -og --verbose --progress "/cygdrive/C/Users/User1/Desktop/testDrive" "/cygdrive/E"
```

Running it (as a non-admin) effectively copies testDrive folder to the root of the E: drive. However, the permissions and ownership of the newly created copy are somehow altered:

[image: Original owners+perms][image: Copied owner+perms]

Top - original folder's owner+permissions, Bottom - copied folder's owner+permissions (some entries removed, two groups added)

Why does this happen even though the rsync is run with options -perms/-og to preserve original perms and ownership?

Comment: It’s important to note that Windows does not have permissions. It has ACLs. I’m not sure whether a version of _rsync_ with support for Windows exists.

Comment: The path `/cygdrive/...` shows that it is not a native Windows program, instead it uses CygWin environment which is some sort of minimal Linux environment and it provides a Linux file-system view with Linux permissions. The Windows file-ACL system can not be fully mapped to a Linux permission system so if you use this rsync version you will always loose some of the permissions.