# Cygwin weird behavior on security permissions

Tags: linux, windows, security, permissions, cygwin

I'm using Cygwin to run periodic backups, for example I do:

`cp -a "$(cygpath C:\Users\S\Documents)" "$BU_FOLDER"`

But I've noticed the commands that create folders or files such as `cp` or `mkdir`, create special permissions on the Properties -> Security tab (on Windows explorer) as to create a POSIX-compatible environment on Windows I believe.

And this causes issues. If you follow these steps, you will get locked out from accessing your files in the copied destination.

- If I run the command above to copy the Documents folder
- And then decide to delete a folder in the destination ($BU_FOLDER/Documents/myfolder)

Then Windows hangs for a little bit, deletes the folder but locks me out from viewing the folder:

[image]

These permissions are added in the security tab when you use `cp` or `mkdir`:

[image]

I can't find a way to remove these permissions from all folders recursively.

Should I stop using Cygwin? These permissions work fine inside Cygwin, I can modify folders and files in the destination but when I do on Windows explorer, these weird unexpected behaviors happen which confuses me as an end user.

Comment: Using Cygwin for the backup of Windows files is a bad idea, especially when so many good and free backup products are available for Windows.

Comment: Related: [Why does Win10 version of rsync modify file owner/perms even if --perms option is set?](https://superuser.com/q/1805567/219095)

Comment: @DanielB oh I actually use Cygwin's rsync to sync my VPS remote folder with my local folder and I never had an issue with it, it doesn't create the unnecessary permissions or change other users permissions.

Comment: I spoke too soon, rsync also creates the said security permissions when syncing local folders!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best and fast way to copy Windows files is to use `Robocopy`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

See option `/COPYALL` for copying also the `NTFS access control list (ACL)`.

Cygwin is using some tricks to simulate Unix permissions
http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/highlights.html#ov-hi-perm
and it is cumbersome to use Cygwin `cp` or `rsync` to duplicate all the Windows permissions.

I would stick to `Robocopy` for Windows files that requires Windows ACL permissions and Cygwin tools for the Files that requires the Cygwin/Unix permissions.

Comment: But I'm looking for a way to remove the Cygwin permissions using a tool or command. I have copied a lot of files this way and as I've stated in the question, I've failed to remove these security attributes, and I'd like to run a command on a parent folder and have all folders and files fixed.

Comment: I would do a clean copy with Robocopy on a separate folder. It is much faster than trying to process all the ACLs specially for directories.

Comment: oh you're proposing that I should just re-copy and use the robocopy option that will turn off copying ACL attributes, that's actually great, I think it's going to work!